# Recreate Moving Median and Moving Mode Excel formula in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, database, median

I am trying to recreate the below Excel formula/table and have True/False display but am stuck.

Excel Formula: **=ABS(ROUND(MEDIAN(C$2:C2),0)-ROUND(MODE.SNGL(C$2:C2),0))<[sample.xlsx]variables!$B$2**

I have 200+ rows of data and I need the Median and the Mode only calculated from the first row to the current row. I can create the Median for all rows in SQL, but this is incorrect for what I need. Same with the Mode. The formula above would be in Excel cell D2 and populated down. The variable it is calling at the end of the formula is just the number **4**.

Any suggestions or pointers would be great. Thanks!

Excel snippet:
[Quick view of how this table looks in Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkFpw.png)

SQL code to build this exact table in SQL.

```
    IF NOT EXISTS (
    select * from sysobjects where name='SampleExample' and xtype='U'
) CREATE TABLE SampleExample (
    [Seconds] INT,
    [Sequence] INT,
    [Value] NUMERIC(12, 9),
    [Result] NVARCHAR(4)
);
INSERT INTO SampleExample VALUES
    (598,1,236.888453364,N'#N/A'),
    (740,2,236.888453364,N'True'),
    (885,3,235.463708639,N'True'),
    (1024,4,236.177295446,N'True'),
    (1189,5,236.177295446,N'True'),
    (1330,6,236.866638064,N'True'),
    (1463,7,236.177295446,N'True'),
    (1599,8,236.866638064,N'True'),
    (1735,9,236.866638064,N'True'),
    (1863,10,236.866638064,N'True'),
    (1986,11,236.866638064,N'True'),
    (2110,12,236.866638064,N'True'),
    (2235,13,236.880749464,N'True'),
    (2362,14,236.908763647,N'True'),
    (2487,15,236.908763647,N'True'),
    (2610,16,236.908763647,N'True'),
    (2739,17,237.190827727,N'True'),
    (2865,18,237.190827727,N'True'),
    (3008,19,237.190827727,N'True'),
    (3132,20,237.190827727,N'True');
```

Current Median Query. I added a column in my SQL table called Filename that is the same value for all rows. But this finds the Median for all rows in the tablet not row 1 through current row.

```
Declare @Median AS INT
Select @Median = ( 
    (Select MAX([Value])
    FROM 
        (Select TOP 50 PERCENT [Value], [Filename] 
        FROM SampleExample 
        
        Order by [Filename]) as BOTTOMHALF)
    + 
    (Select MIN([Value])
    FROM
        (Select TOP 50 PERCENT [Value], [Filename]
        FROM SampleExample 
        
        Order by [Filename] desc) as TOPHALF) ) / 2
```

Current Mode Query:

```
Declare @Mode as INT
Select @Mode = (
    Select TOP 1 ROUND([Value],0) as MODE
    from SampleExample 
    Group by [Value]
    Order by COUNT(*) DESC
    )
```

Result I am looking for is True/False. I'm using CASE in my SQL query:

```
CASE WHEN @Variable > @Median - @Mode THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END AS Result
```

Comment: Please tag your database.

Comment: Please show the SQL you have prepared thus far to get your Median and Mode.

Comment: It would also help to show the expected results from your dataset above (e.g. from your Excel version).

Comment: I've added these additional details the original post. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server (and SQL in general) has a function to calculate medians.  It has the intuitive name `percentile_cont()`.  And, it only exists as a window function, not an aggregation function.

You want a running median.  Ideally, it would be nice to write:

```
select se.*,
       avg(value) over (order by sequence) as avg_value,
       percentile_cont(0.5) over (within group order by sequence) over (order by sequence)
from sampleexample se;
```

But cumulative medians are no supported.  So, that leaves the `apply` option:

```
select se.*, se2.*
from sampleexample se cross apply
     (select top (1)  percentile_cont(0.5) within group (order by value) over () as median,
             avg(value) over () as avg_value
      from sampleexample se2
      where se2.sequence <= se.sequence
     ) se2;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c358b0f65cacff2351d760640f4b324e) is a db<>fiddle.

EDIT:

I really read the question as the median and average, not median and mode (wishful reading on my part).  For the mode, you do need a subquery, so:

```
select se.*, se2.*
from sesampleexample se cross apply
     (select top (1) percentile_cont(0.5) within group (order by value) over () as median,
             avg(value) over () as avg_value,
             value as mode
      from (select se2.*, count(*) over (partition by se2.value) as value_cnt
            from sampleexample se2
            where se2.sequence <= se.sequence
           ) se2
      order by se2.value_cnt desc
     ) se2
```

Comment: Thanks for the enlightening example.  I'm a DB2 user and hadn't until now picked up on CROSS APPLY as being SQL Server's LATERAL JOIN equivalent.  Also I hadn't realized you could use an empty OVER() clause when you have to supply it but don't want a PARTITION BY.  So 2 lessons in one example.  Great!

Comment: BTW, you appear to have calculated Average rather than Mode in your answer?

Comment: Did you perchance overlook adding the subquery for mode? I had to replace `value as mode` in your query with `(SELECT TOP 1 value FROM SampleExample WHERE sequence <= se.sequence GROUP BY value ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC, value) AS mode` to get the expected output.

Comment: `value as mode` doesn't appear to give the correct result for mode. (I checked the sample data with Google Sheets).

Comment: @user9601310 . . . I revised the code and added the db<>fiddle.  The previous version had some "wishful programming" in it.  The logic should now work.

Comment: This is returning exactly what I was trying to achieve, THANKS! I'm not familiar with the CROSS APPLY but will look further into it. Is it possible to have multiple of these in same query or would I need to build sub queries or views? Example would be if I have [value2], [value3], etc in addition to [value] in same original table.